# Store data field from text file into SQL tables

Tags: sql, database, text, store

So I have a text file that I parse my XML file:

```
Current Element :property
name : pkgname
value : 
environment : 

Current Element :property
name : execFilename
value : ${progdir}\execFilename
environment : 

Current Element :property
name : sc_folder
value : xxx_folder
environment : 


Current Element :taskdef
resource : net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml

Current Element :var
name : install_pkg
value : ${basedir}\energia-1.6.10E18-windows.zip

Current Element :var
name : use64bit
value : true

Current Element :var
name : progdir
value : C:\Program Files
```

I want to store this kind of file into my SQL tables, in which I created:

```
CREATE TABLE Property
(
    Name varchar(max),
    Val varchar(max)
);

CREATE TABLE Taskdef
(
    Resources varchar(max)
);

CREATE TABLE Var
(
    Name varchar(max),
    Val varchar(max)
);
```

How would store my data by its current field to the right spot on my tables, for example, if I look for "current element: property" and I want to store the it's attribute "name", then under the table "property", I want to store "pkgname" into the column "name".

Comment: It is microsoft sql server? Do you want to doit in the database server? This is a transac sql code?

Comment: I am using Firebird SQL database. I do not have any experience with database server. I am writing code to create my table in FlameRobin, a GUI of Firebird database.